# How to run a simple java program on cpanel

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I have a simple java socket programming code contains the client.java and server.java

My program only prints out "**you are now connected to the server**" whenever it is connected to the server.java via socket programming.

Both codes works fine when run locally, and now i would like to deploy the server.java on a actual server from cpanel, however thinking about it confuses me on how am i able to run the server.java on cpanel. Can anybody enlighten me on how i'm able to run the server.java on cpanel? Should i convert it to a java web application? Thanks

Comment: are you seriously asking us whether you should convert a java application into a java application?

Comment: @Stultuske i am asking whether to convert the server.java into a java web application so i can manipulate it to run off/on via web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting cpanel aside, do you have access to this remote server in order to copy files over and issue commands ? If so, just transfer your server.java files to the server, compile it & run it. Then do the same for the client part on the client machine. And as long as there are no connection issues (eg firewall etc) between the 2 machines (client & server parts), your application should run just fine.

Comment: thank you for the answer, regarding the compile and run you mentioned. can you advise how should am i able to compile it? yes no connection issues on my end.

Comment: `javac file.java` is the normal command. Otherwise packaging it in a jar would be better and run it as `java -jar yourjarfile`. BTW how did you run it locally ??

Comment: Thank you once again, i'm actually using a jcreator compiler. however, i now have understand your point. using cmd, first i need to get access to my server via cmd then when i'm log in. i can now compile the server.java program. is this right?